# `window.open` function dosen't open a popup windo but do vanish the existing html and other code

Tags: javascript, html, window.open

i have a very simple code which tries to open a popup window but it passes to ruin the whole html and other code.

the code is as follows:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function write(){
/*  var w = String(window.offsetWidth),
        s = String(window.offsetHeight);*/

    var s = window.open('', 'MsgWindow', '_blank');
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="write();" id="writeBtn">Write</button>
</body>
```

so simple but it dosent do anything!

i don't know what is the problem.

## something to note...

- when the button is clicked then the screen goes white and all the element disappear
- when i saw this in google console then what i saw was shocking all the html code just disappear
- i even try to werite in to the variable `s` like `s.document.write('sanmveg')` but that dosen't worked

what is the problem?

Comment: @Teemu: If you're curious about the nested `with`s, I've posted [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29185634/157247) now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rename your function. `document.write()` is being called instead of your function. Calling `document.write()` with no parameters causes unexpected behavior like this.

```js
function mywrite() {
  var s = window.open('', 'MsgWindow');
};
```

```html
<button onclick="mywrite();" id="writeBtn">Write</button>
```

Comment: Tested and verified. You may need to explain the complex environment in which `onXyz` handlers are called, since otherwise `write();` looks like it would only call a global, and of course the `write` in `document.write` isn't a global where the OP's `write` **is**.

Comment: write()  is not a global method , it's a member of a sub object method  so I guess this is not the right answer , is it ?

Comment: @mahmoudnezarsarhan: It is. Paul doesn't seem inclined to explain, so I will.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your `write` function isn't being called; instead, `document.write` is being called. The reason for this is somewhat complex, but the short version is: If you call your function something else that isn't on `document` (or `button` elements), like `openwindow`, it'll work.

So why is `document.write` being called even though you're calling `write()`, expecting it to pick up your global `write` function?

Attribute-based `onxyz` event handlers are called in a complex scope which is effectively a series of nested `with` statements, each mixing in different stuff, and one of the things in that mix is the document object.

When you use an attribute-based `onxyz` event handler on a `button` as you have in your code, the browser generates a handler for you that looks **very roughly** like this:

```
with (document) {
    with (theButton) {
        handler = function() {
            /* This is your attribute text */
            write();
            /* This is the end of your attribute text */
        };
    }
}
```

...and then calls the `handler` function. So when the browser calls your function, it tries to resolve any free symbols in your function, like `write`, against the button element first, then if the button doesn't have a `write` it tries `document`, and then if `document` doesn't have it, it tries the global scope.

But of course, `document` **does** have a `write` function, so it gets called instead of your event handler.

You can actually see this in Chrome, or Firefox with Firebug, by doing this:

1. Create a button with `debugger;` in the `onclick`, e.g.:

   ```
   <button onclick="debugger;">Click Me</button>
   ```
2. Open the page in your browser
3. Open your dev tools / Firebug
4. Click the button

At this point, the debugger will pop up, paused on the `debugger;` statement. Here's what you see in Chrome:

[image]

*(I don't know what the object is that Chrome inserts between the document and the button; it'll be a Chrome-specific implementation detail.)*

And in Firefox+Firebug:

[image]

You can see how the function is nested within a couple of with blocks.

If your `button` were inside a `form`, the `form` would be there too, like this:

```
with (document) {
    with (theForm) {
        with (theButton) {
            handler = function() {
                /* This is your attribute text */
                write();
                /* This is the end of your attribute text */
            };
        }
    }
}
```

...and so free symbols would attempt to resolve against the form element.

Comment: Wonderful answer.  I wish more people took the time to explain the _why_ instead of just the _how_.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should fill the arguments in the proper order , which is :

```
window.open( "URL" , "window name" , "menubar,resizable,width,height,top,left") ;
```

note that the third argument should be a comma-separated string that specify some properties